# typeerror: path can be only a single string

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to run structured streaming using pyspark in local jupyter notebook.
The code reads the csv files from a directory and writes the output stream to the console.

After configuring the spark session:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("stream_from_folder").getOrCreate()
```

Defined the schema:

```
schema = StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), True),\
StructField("name", StringType(), True),StructField("age",  IntegerType(), True),\
StructField("weight",  IntegerType(), True)])
```

When I try to read the stream using:

```
inputDF= spark.readStream.format("csv").schema(schema).option("header",True).\
option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).load("C:/Users/mukun/Documents/datasets/stream_folder")
```

I get

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\streaming.py:467, in DataStreamReader.load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    462     if type(path) != str or len(path.strip()) == 0:
    463         ****raise ValueError(
    464             "If the path is provided for stream, it needs to be a "
    465             + "non-empty string. List of paths are not supported."****
```

When I try to use csv() instead of load(), I get this type of error.

**TypeError: path can be only a single string**

Any idea what might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: I have the same error!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are using a Windows Environment.

Download Winutils from [here](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/releases) and set the Environment Variable `HADOOP_HOME` that is pointing to the folder that contains `bin/winutils.exe`.